# Shell script for copying environment variables into config.json?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, jq

I'm tearing my hair out a bit at this.  I'm trying to write a shell script which indexes through all environment variables, and then overrides variables in a config.json file.

I have a demo angular app which is running in a docker file and I'd like to be able to set config variables as environment variables.  I know it's not the safest approach but this code will never see production and the flexibility it grants me is desirable.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh

env | while IFS= read -r line; do
  value=${line#*=}
  name=${line%%=*}
  
  jq --arg name "$name" --arg value "$value" '.[$name] = $value' src/assets/config.json > src/assets/config.json
done


jq . src/assets/config.json
```

The output json file keeps ending up empty though.

Comment: jq can directly read environment variables. No copy of `/usr/bin/env` and no `while read` loop needed at all in the first place -- and that avoids all the bugs where the `while read` loop doesn't handle variables containing newlines correctly.

Comment: Try `jq ... src/assets/config.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json src/assets/config.json`

Comment: @Philippe, ...there are occasional oddball filesystems like AFS where atomic moves are guaranteed only within the same directory, not across the whole filesystem. Granted, it's even rarer these days than it was twenty years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQ has a built-in `env` function that refers to the current environment and exposes it as a dictionary.

Thus, all you need is:

```
jq -n env >src/assets/config.json
```

...or, to merge an existing config file to add new keys from the environment (and overwrite existing keys where they conflict):

```
if jq '. * env' <src/assets/config.json >src/assets/config.json."$$" ; then
  mv -- src/assets/config.json."$$" src/assets/config.json
else
  rm -f -- src/assets/config.json."$$"
fi
```

Comment: That's perfect, is it possible to have it append/replace the existing config?  It looks like that command just overwrites the whole file so I lose my base config.

Comment: @Andy, sure; updated accordingly.